# Service Fabric Custom Headers Static RemotingContext

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm looking at this project for passing custom headers around Service Fabric Remoting V2 calls.
https://github.com/Expecho/ServiceFabric-Remoting-CustomHeaders

Given the project hasn't been updated in quite a while, I'll ask here also.

Can anyone explain if the static RemotingContext class that is being used to access the headers is actually thread safe in service fabric? I don't see anything that is locking, and know SF uses the very same service instance singleton for all requests.
I see the underlying ConcurrentDictionary for State but it seems to me that concurrent calls to the service might generate some unpredictable results when fetching the headers (the dictionary would just make it thread safe to read/write individual values). I plan to test this shortly.

I've logged an issue on the github repo, but not sure if I should expect any response there and would like to get a resolution on this one fairly quickly.
Can anyone share some thoughts on if this is an issue or if service fabric is forcing some sort of turn-based concurrency that mitigates this being a problem?

If it's not a problem, I would still love a better understanding of what is going on there.

Thanks,
Will

Comment: I've answered using [the issue](https://github.com/Expecho/ServiceFabric-Remoting-CustomHeaders/issues/13) ;-)